# Choose parent/child bundle depends on domain in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.2

Suppose I have two bundles `ParentBundle` and `ChildBundle`. `ChildBundle` "extends" `ParentBundle` by

```
// ChildBundle/ChildBundle.php
<?php

namespace ChildBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

class ChildBundle extends Bundle
{
    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'ParentBundle';
    }

}
```

Then, I copied the routing from `ParentBundle` to `ChildBundle`, and specify which routing to use in `app/config/routing.yml`, as well as rename the `routing.yml` as per [Symfony2 bundle inheritance losing parent bundles routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9373433/symfony2-bundle-inheritance-losing-parent-bundles-routes)

```
// app/config/routing.yml
child:
    resource: "@ChildBundle/Resources/config/routing_child.yml"
    hostname_pattern: child.example.com
    prefix:   /

parent:
    resource: "@ParentBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /
```

After that, I create a template in `ChildBundle` with same path and name, to override the template in `ParentBundle` of the same name.

However, it results in loading the template in `ChildBundle` all the time.

So, my problem is, **How do I load the `ChildBundle` in one domain (i.e. use overriding templates/controllers and such in `ChildBundle`, when user goes into child.example.com) while use `ParentBundle` in another domain (i.e. use overriden templates/controllers and such in `ParentBundle`, when user goes into example.com)?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read this answer I did: [Main page to sub applications on Symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13078662/main-page-to-sub-applications-on-symfony2/13102198#13102198)

In fact you have to create 2 controllers in the web folder, for example:
web/app.php, web/app_child.php

Inside app_child.php, call a new environnement, here called "child":

```
// ...    
$kernel = new AppKernel('child', false);
// ...
```

Create a config_child.yml that will be specific to child bundle, you can paste here the config.yml content or even import config.yml to prevent duplicate code:

```
// config_child.yml
imports:
    - { resource: config.yml }
```

Create a new routing file that includes the routes of child bundle, called routing_child.yml for example, and import this file in config_child.php:

```
framework:
    router:
        resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing_child.yml"
```

Remove the child bundle routes from your classic routing.yml file.

Now play with your web/.htaccess to call the right environnement depending on the subdomain:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # Hit child app
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^child\.example.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app_child.php [QSA,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

That's it, now your applciation will load the right routing config depending on the domain ;)

Comment: My colleague decides that it is too hacky and go for extending controller/template instead. Anyway, thanks for your idea.